# XML dynamically remove duplicated nested sections (in XSLT or PHP)

Tags: xml, xslt

Given an XML that could look something like this -

```
<personseRequest>
    <Row>
      <ServiceLocations>
        <ServiceLocation>
          <LocationId>s</LocationId>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter>
              <Name>s</Name>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
              <Name>s</Name>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
        </ServiceLocation>
        <ServiceLocation>
          <LocationId>s</LocationId>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter>
              <Name>s</Name>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
              <Name>s</Name>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
        </ServiceLocation>
      </ServiceLocations>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <ServiceLocations>
        <ServiceLocation>
          <LocationId>s</LocationId>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter>
              <Name>s</Name>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
              <Name>s</Name>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
        </ServiceLocation>
        <ServiceLocation>
          <LocationId>s</LocationId>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter>
              <Name>s</Name>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
              <Name>s</Name>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
        </ServiceLocation>
      </ServiceLocations>
    </Row>
  <gateways>
    <Row>
      <servicename>s</servicename>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <servicename>s</servicename>
    </Row>
  </gateways>
</personsRequest>
```

I need to remove all duplicated sections to get the following output -

```
<personseRequest>
    <Row>
      <ServiceLocations>
        <ServiceLocation>
          <LocationId>s</LocationId>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter>
              <Name>s</Name>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
        </ServiceLocation>
      </ServiceLocations>
    </Row>
  <gateways>
    <Row>
      <servicename>s</servicename>
    </Row>
  </gateways>
</personsRequest>
```

Note that this needs to work dynamically as the tag names could be different.
I have tried accomplishing this in PHP via DOMXPath but I was not able to do it dynamically.... 
As mentioned, the XML can come in with any name tag or nested name tags and I need to remove all duplicated sections.
Thanks.

Comment: What do they need to have in common to be considered duplicates?

Comment: Do you mean duplicates at any level? Using your example, do you need to remove just the duplicate Rows or say, if a Parameter holds two identical Names, you only need to remove the duplicate name?

Comment: In the XML I am dealing with, all datasets are duplicated and those are the ones I want to single out. so in the above example it is the 'Row', ServiceLocations and 'Parameters' datasets that are duplicated.
So yes, I need to remove duplicates at any level.

Comment: Which version of XSLT can you use? And is the XML at least not having mixed contents (i.e. is it ensured it doesn't have elements with text and element contents like e.g. `<value>10 <unit>m</unit></value>`)?

Comment: I'm fine with version 1 or 2. 
THe XML does not have mixed content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the identity transformation plus an empty template for those elements which have a `deep-equal` preceding sibling to eliminate the duplicates might work but will be rather expensive I think:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[some $prev-sibling in preceding-sibling::* satisfies deep-equal(., $prev-sibling)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26mq/1

The example is XSLT 3 but for XSLT 2 you just need to drop the `xsl:mode` declaration and spell out the identity transformation with a template

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works @ 99%. 
The only issue I have currently is when there is something like -

-----------------------------------------
  <watchlists_requested>
    <Row></Row>
    <Row></Row>
  </watchlists_requested>
----------------------------------------
Your code turns that into 
-------------------------------------
  <watchlists_requested>
    </Row>
  </watchlists_requested>
----------------------------------------
When I want it as - 
------------------------------------- 
<watchlists_requested>
    <Row></Row>
  </watchlists_requested>

Comment: @DanAbittan, it is not clear from your comment what is missing, I don't know how to interpret that `-----------------------------------------` stuff and `<watchlists_requested> </Row>` is also not syntactically possible. Consider asking a new question where you can put the necessary details in a well-formatted code sample.

Comment: sorry I can't indent in a comment so here is the xml 
<watchlists_requested> <Row></Row> <Row></Row> </watchlists_requested> 
Your code turns that into
<watchlists_requested> </Row> </watchlists_requested>  
 I want it as 
 <watchlists_requested> <Row></Row> </watchlists_requested>

Comment: @DanAbittan, as I already said, `<watchlists_requested> </Row> ` makes no sense to me (you can't open one tag (e.g. `<watchlists_requested>`) and then close another one (e.g. `</Row>`), either edit your question or ask a new one where you show code samples in a well-formatted way.